# Multi variable limits and domain

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{x^2-y^2}$ show that the $lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist.

I was told the following if the point $(a,b)$ cannot be approached from all paths the limit does not exist, and to test this by substituting various relevant curves into $f$ and that if $f_n\neq f_m$ then this proofs that the limit does not exist this seems like a very cumbersome method.

but

If I find the domain of $f(x,y)$ $D{\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2|x=y\}}$ I could just say that the point $(0,0)$ is on the line $x=y$ and that it cannot be approached on the line $x=y$ as it is out of the domain.

Is this reasoning correct? 
Are there cases that this does not apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct, but that is not the only reason why a limit could not exists. For instance, the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$$ does not exists, but the function is well defined by every path approaching to the point $(0,0)$. The reason why this limit does not exists is, in this case, the fact that approaching to the point $(0,0)$ through different paths may produce different results.

For example, if we approach to (0,0) through the line $x=0$, we get

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0), $x=0$} \dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{y\to 0} \dfrac{(0)^2}{(0)^2+y^2}=0$$

while if we approach to (0,0) through the line $x=y$ we get

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0), $x=y$} \dfrac{y^2}{y^2+y^2}=\lim_{y\to 0} \dfrac{y^2}{2y^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$.

So, the limit does not exist. You can think of this as the analog in one variable of an example where both side limits $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ existed but were different, and one concluded that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ did not exist.

Comment: approaching to the point (0,0) through different paths may produce different results. -- is this not a direct result of $(0,0)$ being out of the domain of $f$?

Comment: Since you are asking about the limit, it does not matter if $(0,0)$ is in the domain of the function or not. The thing that matters is what happen with the values $f(x)$ as $x$ goes "infinitely-close" to $(0,0)$. As an example, you might think about the famous limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1$. Note that $x=0$ is not in the domain of the function $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$, but still the limit exists.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $y=mx$.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{m^2x^2}{x^2(1-m^2)}=\frac{m^2}{1-m^2}$$

The limit depends on the choice of m, hence the initial limit does not exist.